# Why is my module not found when imported in ipython's shell?

Tags: python

I have a small python file called `test.py`:

```py
def hello(name):
    print(f"Hello {name}, how are you?")
```

When I start ipython, i try to import and test the function, here is what happens

```py
In [1]: import test                                                                         
                                                                                            
In [2]: test.hello("Joe")                                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------                 
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)                 
Input In [2], in <cell line: 1>()                                                           
----> 1 test.hello("Joe")                                                                 
                                                                                            
AttributeError: module 'test' has no attribute 'hello'
```

The shell has been launched at the same level where the file actually is.

Did I miss something?

Comment: There is a built-in package named `test`, name your module something else. https://docs.python.org/3/library/test.html

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/test.html#module-test

Comment: Thank you. Didn't think about that at all. This is embarrassing. Can you post as a reply so I can validate your answer?